# Show that $\left\{z:|z|\leq 3, |Re(z)|\geq 1\right\}$ is not connected.

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

> Show that $\left\{z:|z|\leq 3, |Re(z)|\geq 1\right\}$ is not connected.

I already showed this set was compact by the Heine-Borel theorem. Visually, I imagine this set to look like a "half circle" centered at the origin with $Re(z)\in [1,3]$. Am I even right? Anyway, how do I show this set is not connected? Do I use the closure of its open version and path-connectedness? Any tips are appeciated!

Comment: It does seem connected to me, as it is convex.

Comment: Your mental picture of the set is good. But it should also give you the hint that it is connected.

Comment: My reading of the set is that it's a circle with a vertical middle piece cut out - note that it's not just Re(z) >= 1, it's abs(Re(z)) >= 1, so there's a left part and a right part, and so you just need to prove that those two separate parts do indeed result in a non-connected set.

Comment: I don't think it is connected: it is two pieces of canonical disk of radius $\;\sqrt3\;$. one with real part $\;\ge1\;$ , another with real part $\;\le-1\;$ ...and in the middle of these two pieces (and not containing it!) there are all the points in the disc with $\;|Re\,z|<1\;$

Comment: Hmm, I don't recall seeing the absolute value around $\operatorname{Re}(z)$. Sorry. Of course, it is disconnected in that case.

Comment: @xyzzyz It's $\lvert \operatorname{Re} z\rvert\ge1$, not $ \operatorname{Re} z\ge1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$C:=\{\;z\in\Bbb C\;|\;|z|\le3\,,\,\,|\text{Re}\,z|\ge1\;\}$$

and observe for example that $\;-1,\,1\in C\;$, yet any path connecting this two points must necessarily intersect the imaginary axis (the $\;y\,-$ axis) and there the real part of numers equals zero and thus cannot be in $\;C\;$ , meaning $\;C\;$ isn't path connected.

Now, you can also take $\;A:=\{\,z\in C\;|\;\text{Re}\,z\ge1\,\}\;$ and $\;B:=\{\,z\in C\;|\;\text{Re}\,z\le1\,\}\;$ . Then both $\;A,B\;$ are non-empty closed in $\;C\;$ and $\;A\cap B=\emptyset\;,\;\;A\cup B=C\;$ , so $\;C\;$ isn't connected, either.

Comment: Thanks! I think my bad was my visualization of it. I realized the real part has two cases. Then it definitely makes sense the set is disconnected!

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be your set. Consider a function $f: C \to \{-1, 1\}$, $f(z) = \frac{\operatorname{Re} z}{|\operatorname{Re} z|}$. $f$ is well defined, since $\operatorname{Re}z \ne 0$ for all $z \in C$. It is continuous, and onto a disconnected discrete set, hence the domain cannot be continuous, since the image of connected set is connected.